# How do you integrate microservices that are distributed across domains and platforms?

Tags: microservices, cloud-computing, domain-name-system

Modern webapps have multiple microservices that may be on multiple domains (e.g. subdomains) and providers (e.g. both AWS and Google Cloud; or Google Container Engine Google App Engine within the Google Cloud).

Yet there are reasons to present these together. For example, Content Distribution Networks and security services are often   designed to work on one (or a few domains and source platforms).

What are best practices in  presenting microservices in an integrated way? Gateways? Load balancers? Or perhaps skip the integration and accept the heterogeneity?

Comment: What's meant by "integrating" here? The point of microservices is that you obtain results for different tasks from *different* addresses. Does it really matter *just how* different they are? For the computer, example.com/services/alpha?input=3 isn't any "more similar" to example.com/services/beta?input=3 than to external.provider/web-api/transform/bydecimal/3. Either way you need to configure two different addresses for the two tasks.

Comment: CDNs and WAFs expect you to expose your service at one (or a few) endpoints (i.e. one  domain) and on one cloud platform.

The server-side may call many  our our own microservices and external  SaaSes, but that's not a problem. My question is about having multiple exposed microservices.